# Keep a dialog when a Codename One app goes from background to foreground

Tags: codenameone

By default, Codename One has this code:

```
public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
        hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));
        hi.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = getCurrentForm();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = getCurrentForm();
        }
    }
```

First question: why are dialogs disposed by default when the app goes to background?

Second question: how can I keep the dialogs showing when the app goes from background to foreground? In my app, this default disposing causes that the user is forced to tap two times on the same button that shows a dialog, causing that same REST request is sent two times, with unwanted effects. However I have a lot of dialogs and to check the effect of an automatic disposing is problematic, that's why I'm asking if it's possible to avoid at all this automatic disposing (without side effects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recommend that people don't do anything more elaborate than a "yes/no" question in a `Dialog`. By default dialogs are modal so when you call `show()` on it the call will be blocked.

This is problematic in the lifecycle methods as they're executed in sequence and would fail as a result. The solution you listed is to not have a dialog when suspending the app, that's a good direction.

If you still want to show a dialog in this case you can do a special case for that specific dialog and show it using one of the modless methods when start() is reinvoked.